# calling python script from php

Tags: php, python, variables, io

Totally baffled here. I'm looking to call a Python script from a PHP script and pass a few variables.

This works:

```
$tst =50.0;
$myfile="/usr/local/bin/myP2.py $tst 0.0";
echo exec ($myfile);
```

But this doesn't:

```
$value1 = $_GET['firstFloatValue'];
$myfile="/usr/local/bin/myP2.py $value1 0.0";
echo exec ($myfile);
```

The only difference between the two cases is that in the second case, the variable is derived from a `$_GET` function. Printing `$value1` yields a simple float value. I'm a noob in PHP and Python, so apologies if this is something simple.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Did you check whether `$_GET['firstFloatValue']` is really `50.0` ?

Comment: Not really related to Python.